# Use node.js req.params.id and insert the matching id data into a modal with in the same page

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Hello I am needing assistance with inserting data from the body to a modal based on the user selection. For example I have a page with buttons, each button data contains a first and last name. When the user selects the button I use req.params.id to match the data from the mongoDB to return the name. I get how to do this with two different pages but I want to do it with one page.

Here is my code to render the route and get all the data from the mongoDB,

```
app.get("/timesheet", (req, res) => {
    Reg.find({}, (err, allReg) => {
        if(err){
            console.error(err);
        } else (
            res.render("log", { reg: allReg })
        )
    });
});
```

I than use EJS to perform a forEach to display each set of data, currently displaying them as buttons using the anchor element so I can set the href with the params.id.

```
<% reg.forEach(function(entries){ %>
<a href="/timesheet/<%= entries._id %>" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#childList">
    <%= entries.firstName %>
    <%= entries.lastName %>
</a>
  <% }); %>
  </div>
```

Here is the route to get the req.params.id

```
app.get("/timesheet/:id", (req, res) => {
    Reg.findById(req.params.id, (err, foundReg) => {
        if(err){
            console.error(err);
        } else {
        res.render("log", { reg: foundReg });
        }
    });
});
```

When I click on any of the buttons a modal opens, I want the relating data to display in the modal. Each button opens the same modal but it should be dynamic based on the button the user clicks on.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="childList" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="childListLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="childListLabel"></h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                   <%= reg.firstName %>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Check In</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```